# InteractiveMarkerControl menu mode shows on left click

Tags: ros, interactive-markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have an interactive marker whose interaction mode is MENU. The menu should only display when the marker is right clicked; however, it activates on either right or left click. The menu marker in the basic controls demo exhibits the same behavior. Do I need to specify which mouse button it uses, or is there a bug somewhere? I'm in Ubuntu 12.04 with ROS Groovy.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56087/interactivemarkercontrol-menu-mode-shows-on-left-click/) by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 452 on 2013-02-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The behaviour of menu controls was changed in groovy. Use a button control to get the right-click behaviour.

---

Originally posted by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) with karma: 1444 on 2013-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) on 2013-02-23**:
Thanks, dgossow. For anyone with this problem, some of the ROS tutorial code is outdated. See: http://answers.ros.org/question/56085/interactivemarker-with-multiple-interaction-modes/